# Creating IOS purchase on Ruby on Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, app-store-connect, fastlane

If somebody knows the way that i can create in-app purchases for IOS from my admin panel (written on Ruby with ROR) I would really appreciate your help. I know Google provides this functionality to add in-apps throw his api, I hope that Apple does too. I watched docs of [Fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane) gem and didn't found anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spaceship](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship/lib/spaceship/tunes) from Fastlane includes the ability to create and manage IAPs:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/lib/spaceship/tunes/iap.rb

Otherwise you only have the "ugly" iTMSTransporter to upload IAPs, I don't think it allows to actually create them on iTC.